# Robo reviewing and spam

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, review-queues

I hate to call out a fellow active user, but should we perhaps have checks for robo reviewing as they do on Stack Overflow. There is no way in hell that [this edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/121223) could under any circumstances be regarded as anything other than spam.

Google maps is apparently:

> Saini Cosmetics basement , Gali No 1 A D Block Plot No 365, Ratiya
>   Marg, Sangam Vihar, Delhi 110080.

As it happens, that tag wiki could be improved considerably, but that is a different matter.

Comment: *as they do on Stack Overflow* - Please provide a link

Comment: I'm also interested as to why one user approved the edit...

Comment: If you have improvement for the tag wiki, please feel free to edit it.

Comment: @Midavalo - I'm sure it was a misclick. I have also fallen victim to this and unfortunately, I don't think there is an undo button :)

Comment: @Joseph I am hoping so, although sometimes I think people approve everything without checking it (brash generalisation here, not singling out any user) :)

Comment: @Midavalo. I can't provide a link, but I can tell you from several years reviewing on both gis.se and Stack Overflow that on SO they occasionally get you to review edits, answers, etc as a check that you are paying attention. I know because I failed a couple of checks on closing questions :-)

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça I understand what you're talking about now - the review audits.

Comment: @Joseph, yes, I don't want to single out a user either, especially not an active one. Perhaps there should be an undo review option?

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça We are unable to make changes to the functionality of GIS.SE - this kind of suggestion needs to be made on [Meta.SE] for the SE devs to see and implement (if appropriate).

Comment: @Midavalo. Really, according to the stats: "whyzar has approved 665 edit suggestions and rejected 1 edit suggestion and improved 12 edit suggestions". As I said, I don't want to single out a user, though I have, but that is hardly a first edit review.

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça sorry I was referring to the editor not the reviewer... Too early in the morning :)

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça - Relevant: [How to undo/fix an accidentally wrong review?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298175/how-to-undo-fix-an-accidentally-wrong-review)

Comment: OK, it's not a big deal. In fact, the SO approach can be quite stresful when you are genuinely trying to help and I find GIS.SE much more relaxed. This particular edit was so egregious that I couldn't let it go.

Comment: I sympathise with your question (due to own experience). However, only the evidences provided here (example and review stats) are enough to indicate poor review activity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Review Audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work) are currently active only on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), and [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Until/unless they are extended to GIS SE we can only encourage everyone to do due diligence when working in the review queues.

Certainly, the example that you linked to should not have been approved.